# How to say "at music" as in "Better than me at music" in french?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, comparatifs

Or how do you say "He's better than me at playing music" or "Better than me at classical music" in French. Do you say "Il est mieux que moi dans/a/sur la musique classique"? Or is that wrong? How do you say "at subject/skill" in French?

Comment: @stéphane gimenez Est-ce qu'on considère que "French/in French" doit être retiré dans les questions vu la nature du site / est-ce que ça justifie une modification uniquement pour ça ? Merci.

Comment: @comet: Je me suis déjà posé cette question, et je me suis dit que les retirer peut parfois compliquer la tâche des moteurs de recherche. Mais je ne sais pas si c'est le cas.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Je pense que c'est effectivement un risque, et puis, pour les gens qui sont sur plusieurs forums ici, le jour où ils ont la tête dans le... derrière, je te laisse imaginer la cata. ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When used as a comparative of *bon*, better translates to *meilleur*. There are several way to translate "at".

> *Il est meilleur que moi en musique classique.*
>
> *Il est meilleur que moi comme* (or *en tant qu'*) *interprète de musique classique.*
>
> *Il est meilleur que moi au piano.*
>
> *Il joue la musique classique mieux que moi.* (comparative of *bien*)